# Outlook for Mac: Using Javascript API version 1.4

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins, outlook-for-mac

According to the compatibility table in [this Microsoft website](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/tutorial-api-requirement-sets) version 1.4 of the Javascript API for Office, is compatible with Outlook for Mac 2016.

However, I'm using the latest version 15.33 of Outlook for Mac (not insider) - and when I change

`<Requirements>
     <Sets>
       <Set Name="MailBox" MinVersion="1.3" />
     </Sets>
   </Requirements>`

in the manifest file to `1.4` the add-in disappears from Outlook for Mac - my add-in displays a side pane on the composition form of an calendar event.

Why is it that?

Answer (score 0):

what is the exact build number that you are using? If it is < 15.33(170225) then it will not show. Use any build on or above 15.33 (170225).

Comment: My Version is 15.33 (170409) and after I changed my manifest to 1.4 the add-in button on the compose form disappeared and showed again when I changed back to 1.3...